# APOC UUID support in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm running a Neo4j instance (version 4.2.2) in a pod within a Kubernetes cluster, in standalone mode. The server starts, I can create, find and update nodes and relationships, however, when trying to install a UUID using `apoc.uuid.install`, the procedure hangs and never seems to finish.

I'd also like to mention that `apoc.uuid.enabled=true` is set in neo4j.conf, I've set a constraint on the designated UUID field before running install and I can't find any errors in the logs. I've also tried this functionality in non-K8s environments and I have no problem using it there.

The helm charts used for this deployment are taken from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-helm.

Did anyone experience this behavior? If yes, how did you manage to solve it?